# HTML CSS положение элементов при z-index;

Tags: html, css

Есть следующий код:

```html
<body>
<div style="z-index: 2;position: absolute;background: yellow;top: 0;left: 50px;">
z-index 2
</div>
</body>

<div style="z-index: 1;position: absolute;background: red;">
z-index 1
<div style="z-index: 3;background: blue;top: 0;position: absolute;left: 50px;">
z-index 3
</div>
</div>
```

Имеем 1 блок в body с `z-index: 2`, и другой блок вне body с `z-index: 1` и блок внутри него с `z-index: 3`;

Вопрос: как сделать чтобы блок с `z-index: 3;` был поверх того что с `z-index: 2`? При том чтобы не менять `z-index: 1` родителя.

Comment: Я правильно понял, вы хотите чтобы блок с z-index: 2 был поверх блока с z-index: 1 но при этом под блоком с z-index: 3?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="z-index: 1;position: absolute;background: yellow;top: 0;left: 50px;">
z-index 2
```

в z-index 2, сделать z-index равным родителю нужного вам блока, то есть 1